# Disabling the soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I need to disable soft keyboard, and enable only hard one, so I created this kind of edittext, It works really good, but on some htc phones this type of edittext disabling multiline statement(don't know how it works).

```
public class NoImeEditText extends EditText {
    public NoImeEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

another way I using this kind of code and it doesn't work.

```
    keyboardText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);


    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getMainActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm != null)
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(keyboardText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might works,

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

This will hide soft keyboard.